# C++11 Best Practice: When to accept by value vs const&?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, move

I was satisfied with the 'rule' to accept by value when you intend to *store* the object, and accept by const reference when you only need to access it. This way, you (the writer of a class) doesn't choose whether to copy the user of the class's variable or whether to move it, they do. But in use I've been getting increasingly unsure about the soundness of that advice; *move* isn't a uniform in cost operation...

```
struct Thing
{
    std::array<int, 10000> m_BigArray;
};

class Doer
{
    public:
        Doer(Thing thing) : m_Thing(std::move(thing)) {}

    private:
        Thing m_Thing;
};

int main()
{
    Thing thing;
    Doer doer1(std::move(thing)); // user can decide to move 'thing'
    // or
    Doer doer2(thing); // user can decide to copy 'thing'
}
```

In the above example, move is as expensive as copy. So, instead of taking a const reference and copying the object once, you end up moving it (effectively copying it) twice. The user does it once into your argument, and you do it again into your member.

This gets further exacerbated even when moving is significantly cheaper than copying (pretend moving thing is some unknown cost below, but cheaper than copying):

```
struct A
{
    A(Thing thing) : m_Thing(std::move(thing)) {}
    Thing m_Thing;
};

struct B : A
{
    B(Thing thing) : A(std::move(thing)) {}
};

struct C : B
{
    C(Thing thing) : B(std::move(thing)) {}
};

struct D : C
{
    D(Thing thing) : C(std::move(thing)) {}
};
```

Here, you have will either end up with 1 copy and 4 moves, or 5 moves. If all the constructors accepted a const reference it would only be 1 copy. Now I have to weigh what's move expensive, 1 copy or 5 moves.

What's the best advice for handling these situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the best advice for handling these situations?

My best advice is to do what you're doing:  Think for yourself.  Don't trust everything you hear.  Measure.

Below I've taken your code and instrumented it with print statements.  I've also added a 3rd case: Initializing from a prvalue:

The test tries things two ways:

1. Pass by value.
2. Overload on passing by `const&` and `&&`:

Code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct Thing
{
    Thing() = default;
    Thing(const Thing&) {std::cout << "Thing(const Thing&)\n";}
    Thing& operator=(const Thing&) {std::cout << "operator=(const Thing&)\n";
                                    return *this;}
    Thing(Thing&&) {std::cout << "Thing(Thing&&)\n";}
    Thing& operator=(Thing&&) {std::cout << "operator=(Thing&&)\n";
                                    return *this;}
};

class Doer
{
    public:
#if PROCESS == 1
        Doer(Thing thing) : m_Thing(std::move(thing)) {}
#elif PROCESS == 2
        Doer(const Thing& thing) : m_Thing(thing) {}
        Doer(Thing&& thing) : m_Thing(std::move(thing)) {}
#endif

    private:
        Thing m_Thing;
};

Thing
make_thing()
{
    return Thing();
}

int main()
{
    Thing thing;
    std::cout << "lvalue\n";
    Doer doer1(thing); // user can decide to copy 'thing'
    std::cout << "\nxvalue\n";
    Doer doer2(std::move(thing)); // user can decide to move 'thing'
    std::cout << "\nprvalue\n";
    Doer doer3(make_thing()); // user can decide to use factor function
}
```

For me when I compile with -DPROCESS=1 I get:

```
lvalue
Thing(const Thing&)
Thing(Thing&&)

xvalue
Thing(Thing&&)
Thing(Thing&&)

prvalue
Thing(Thing&&)
```

And with -DPROCESS=2:

```
lvalue
Thing(const Thing&)

xvalue
Thing(Thing&&)

prvalue
Thing(Thing&&)
```

So passing by value costs an extra move construction over passing by overloaded references for the lvalue and xvalue cases.  And as you've noted, a move construction isn't necessarily cheap.  It can be as expensive as a copy construction.  On the upside, you only have to write 1 overload with pass-by-value.  Passing by overloaded references requires 2^N overloads where N is the number of parameters.  Quite doable at N==1, getting unwieldy at N==3.

Also as you noted your second example is just your first exacerbated.

When performance is your primary concern, and especially when you can't count on a cheap move constructor, pass by overloaded rvalue references.  When you can count on a cheap move construction, and/or you do not want to deal with an unreasonable (you get to define unreasonable for yourself) number of overloads, use pass-by-value.  There is no one answer that is always right for everyone in every situation.  C++11 programmers still have to think.

Answer (score 1):

Often cited [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) gives this question a detailed treatment:

> ... although the compiler is normally required to make a copy when a function parameter is passed by value (so modifications to the parameter inside the function can’t affect the caller), it is allowed to elide the copy, and simply use the source object itself, when the source is an rvalue.

Comment: Should be a comment unless you're going to quote the relevant passages from the linked text,.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The compiler will not implicitly move in any of the places move is used in the question.  I have not yet down voted.  Giving you a chance to delete or correct it.

Comment: @HowardHinnant you are right, the last part was my wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include it as a choice, but may I suggest perfect forwarding?

```
class Doer
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Doer(T&& thing) : m_Thing(std::forward<T>(thing)) {}

private:
    Thing m_Thing;
};
```

This will result in a single copy/move for lvalues/rvalues, which is exactly what we want.

Comment: I thought about including this in my answer and decided not to because of the extra complexity.  This can be used to get the same expense as overloading with references.  However you really don't want to do it in an overly generic fashion as currently shown.  When `T` is unconstrained, traits such as `std::is_constructible<Doer, X>` give a false positive.  To prevent this you need to constrain `T` to be a `Thing` and this typically adds more complexity than just adding a single overload.  This technique becomes more attractive when you need it to avoid an unreasonable number of overloads.

Comment: `std::tuple` is a wonderful place to use this technique! (as long as it is properly constrained).

Comment: @HowardHinnant By constraining, I suspect you mean `std::enable_if`?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer only, but in the second example you gave, the moves could have been avoided by explicitly inheriting A's base ctor:

```
struct B : A
{
    using A::A;
};

struct C : B
{
    using A::A;
};

struct D : C
{
    using A::A;
};
```

Here'll you end up with 1 copy vs 1 move.

Answer (score -6):

Here's some additional rules that will fix the problem:

1. Never derive from a concrete class. A concrete, instantiable class is already completely implemented. Deriving from it is bad use of inheritance. => your constructor parameter cost disappears.
2. Decide between pass-by-value and pass-by-const-reference in data members based on whether the data is inside or outside your current object.
3. If there are constructor parameters in a class, there should also be a data member *in the same class*. Passing the parameter to a base class is not a good idea.
4. Forget std::move. The cost of copying the data is not large enough. It takes more time for programmers to type std::move everywhere than the practise saves in execution time.
5. If you're constantly creating and destroying those objects, that takes more time than whatever you are saving with std::move.

Comment: Dude. That's so wrong it's funny. We can understand *you* can't use `std::move`, but don't spread this nonsense.

Comment: `Passing the parameter to a base class is not a good idea` WTF?

Comment: `for programmers to type std::move everywhere` Why are you typing `std::move` everywhere?

Comment: lightness: see the examples. std::move used 6 times in small example.

Comment: @tp1: It's a contrived example, buddy. That hardly counts as every programmer using it "everywhere".

Comment: lightness: I bet it took him at least 20 seconds to write those 6 std::moves. There is no way the above code is ever going to save 20 seconds in execution time. Count the number of objects he needs to create before it happen!

Comment: @tp1: Yes, because he will only ever run that program once, and then discard it. That's what we do!

Comment: @tp1: And, because that is his real code. His real objects don't have expensive resources attached, or any large memory buffers. They are definitely copyable and always will be.

Comment: @tp1: `</extreme_sarcasm>`

Comment: @lightness: There is stuff to learn from this. Copy-optimizations have  caused large amount of unnecessary waste of time and broken designs. Std::move has potential to cause the same again -- it's only useful if it actually saves time.

Comment: @tp1: Sure. That's a far cry from "forget `std::move`".

Comment: @lightness: Another reason for using std::move is just needed. Execution time is not a valid reason.

Comment: @lightness: You have to be a little insane to keep software working for long periods of time, when failures are not acceptable.

Comment: @tp1: Yeah but not like this

Comment: *It takes more time for programmers to type std::move everywhere than the practise saves in execution time* - in the accepted answer `std::move` is used only twice - once in the ctor to copy an xvalue and once in the test code to show its usage. OP probably overused it it his example, yes. But I personally can't wait to start using c++11 features on daily basis - I'd better see std::move occasionally then e.g. `delete *it`(or horrible macros magic) everywhere where you want to keep owned object pointer in an array.